# pip install pyinstaller no module named pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyinstaller

I wanted to install `pyinstaller` module with the following command:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

But I always get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I tried everything, but finally i found the solution.

You just have to downgrade your **pip** from version **19** to **18.1** :

```
pip install pip==18.1
```

Then install PyInstaller :

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

.

As you see i managed to install it :

[image]
.

After that you can upgrade again your pip :

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this up, it definitely helped!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem when using pip-19.0.1 because as the other answer suggests, using 18.1 works fine.

But also now pip-19.0.3 has been released and upgrading to that seems to fix the issue.

So I suggest you try to update pip and then install pyinstaller

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install pyinstaller
```