# PyInstaller failing to install through pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyinstaller

pip 19.0.1 from c:\users\halzein\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Trying to install PyInstaller with this command:

`pip3 install PyInstaller --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`

(I get errors if I try to use pip without trusted-host tags)

And the install keeps failing due to this error after downloading and installing build dependencies:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyInstaller'`

---

`Command "c:\users\halzein\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe c:\users\halzein\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel C:\Users\halzein\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfwtrnagf" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\halzein\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-thcvcr0q\PyInstaller\`

Not really sure what's causing this, and my searches have come up with nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54338715/7976758

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced same error, here's what worked for me:

Run windows powershell as administrator, and downgrade pip to 18.1 by typing `pip install pip==18.1` this will uninstall 19.0.1 and install 18.1 version. After that just run `pip install pyinstaller` and it should finish it with no errors. Than you can upgrade pip to 19.0.1 with `python -m pip install –upgrade pip`

Hope this help you too.

Cheers =)

Comment: Fix worked for me!

Issue persists using: •Python==3.6.4 •pip>=19.0.3 && pip<=20.3.3 •setuptools>=41.0.0 && setuptools<=51.3.3